# Make a mx:DataGrid transparent in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, transparent, alpha

I am developing an app on AIR 1.5 and Flex 4. Can anyone please tell me how to make a `mx:DataGrid` in Flex with a transparent background. All of the tutorials I have found seem to suggest adjusting the `backgroundAlpha` to 0 but so far as i can tell Flex 4 components do not support this property, so how can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set grid's `borderSkin` to something empty or transparent, e.g. to empty skin:

```
borderSkin="mx.skins.ProgrammaticSkin"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I love you moropus. Could you also tell me a good resource on learning flex 4. I am always stumped on all these little problems.

Comment: Hey, if its not too much trouble could you plz post a small example as well.